# If a file named `picture_test.aux` is missing for the graphicx package, then where can I get a copy of the file, and where do I put it?

Tags: graphics, includegraphics

#### If a file named `picture_test.aux` is missing for the `graphicx` package, then where can I get a copy of the file, and where in the LaTeX installation do I put it?

---

#### Code

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics{./BLUE_AND_ORANGE_CARDS/FINAL_PROOFS/1_ENGLISH_ORANGE_ENGLISH_BOTTLE.PNG}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

#### The Console Output is Shown Below

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 24.1) (preloaded format=pdflatex.fmt)
restricted \write18 enabled.

entering extended mode
(C:/FILES/FUN_WORK_PROJECTS/WIP_WORK_IN_PROGRESS/SPANISH_FOR_PEOPLE_WHO_ARE_MOR
E_COMFORTABLE_WITH_ENGLISH/FLASH_CARDS_SPANISH_ENGLISH/CARDS/BLUE_AND_ORANGE_CA
RDS/picture_test.tex

LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1

L3 programming layer <2024-01-04>

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls

Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo))

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty)

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg)|

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def)))

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/I3backend\|3backend-pdftex.def)

No file picture_test.aux.

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mkii

[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]

) (C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-base.sty

(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/O0miktex\epstopdf-sys.cfg))

LaTeX Warning: File °./BLUE_LAND_ORANGE_CARDS/FINAL_PROOFS/FINAL_PROOFS/1_ENGLIS
H_ORANGE_ENGLISH_BOTTLE.PNG' not found on input line 8.

! Package pdftex.def Error: File “./BLUE_LAND_ORANGE_CARDS/FINAL_PROOFS/FINAL_PR
QOFS/1_ENGLISH_ORANGE_ENGLISH_BOTTLE.PNG' not found: using draft setting,

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation,

Type H <return> for immediate help.

L8 ...PROOFS/1_ENGLISH_ORANGE_ENGLISH_BOTTLE.PNG}

?
```

---

#### Edit

Someone asked me to describe the file hierarchy...

Here it is...

```
print current working directory (pwd)...
 C:\FILES\FUN_WORK_PROJECTS\WIP_WORK_IN_PROGRESS\SPANISH_FOR_PEOPLE_WHO_ARE_MORE_COMFORTABLE_WITH_ENGLISH\FLASH_CARDS_SPANISH_ENGLISH\CARDS\BLUE_AND_ORANGE_CARDS
```

```
.\
|-- picture_test.tex
|-- FLASHCARD_TARJETA_GATO_CAT.xcf
+-- FINAL_PROOFS
|    |-- 10_ENGLISH_ORANGE_MAN_HOMBRE.PNG
|    |-- 10_SPANISH_BLUE_MAN_HOMBRE.PNG
|    |-- 11_ENGLISH_woman_mujer.png
|    |-- 11_SPANISH_woman_mujer.png
|    |-- 12_ENGLISH_GRIFIO_SILCOCK_FAUCET_SPIGOT_WATER_TAP.PNG
|    |-- 12_SPANISH_GRIFIO_SILCOCK_FAUCET_SPIGOT.PNG
|    |-- 13_ENGLISH_dog_perro.PNG
|    |-- 13_SPANISH_dog_perro.PNG
|    |-- 14A_ENGLISH_DEER_VENADO.png
|    |-- 14A_SPANISH_DEER_VENISON_VENADO.png
|    |-- 15_ENGLISH_PAINTERS_PALLET.png
|    |-- 15_SPANISH_PAINTERS_PALLET.png
|    |-- 16_ENGLISH_LIQUIDORA.jpg
|    |-- 16_SPANISH_LIQUIDORA.jpg
|    |-- 17_ENGLISH_CLAMP.jpg
|    |-- 17_SPANISH_ABRAZEDERA_CLAMP.jpg
|    |-- 18_FLASHCARD_TARJETA_TAPA_DEL_PLUG_ELECTRICAL_OUTLET_COVER.png
|    |-- 19_ENGLISH_ORANGE_LION.png
|    |-- 19_SPANISH_BLUE_LION.png
|    |-- 1_ENGLISH_ORANGE_ENGLISH_BOTTLE.PNG
|    |-- 1_SPANISH_BLUE_BOTTLE.PNG
|    |-- 2_ENGLISH_CAT.PNG
|    |-- 2_SPANISH_CAT_GATO.PNG
|    |-- 3B_ENGLISH_MOUNTAIN_MONTAÑA.png
|    |-- 3B_SPANISH_MOUNTAIN_MONTAÑA.png
|    |-- 3_ENGLISH_MOUNTAIN_MONTAÑA.png
|    |-- 3_SPANISH_MOUNTAIN_MONTAÑA.png
|    |-- 4_ENGLISH_TOWELS_TOWALLAS_ORANGE.PNG
|    |-- 4_SPANISH_TOWELS_TOWALLAS_BLUE.PNG
|    |-- 5_ENGLISH_ORANGE_SQUIRREL.png
|    |-- 5_SPANISH_BLUE_SQUIRREL.png
|    |-- 6_ENGLISH_ORANGE_LIGHT.png
|    |-- 6_SPANISH_BLUE_LIGHT.png
|    |-- 7_ENGLISH_ORANGE_LEAF_HOJA.png
|    |-- 7_SPANISH_BLUE_TREE_LEAVES_HOJA_DEL_ARBOL.png
|    |-- 8_ENGLISH_GOLDEN_GEAR_ORANGE.PNG
|    |-- 8_SPANISH_SILVER_GEAR_BLUE.PNG
|    |-- 9_ENGLISH_FLASHCARD_COINS_v2.png
|    |-- 9_ENGLISH_ORANGE_COINS.PNG
|    |-- 9_SPANISH_BLUE_COINS.PNG
|    |-- 9_SPANISH_FLASHCARD_COINS_v2.png
|    +-- CARDS_FOR_LEARNING_SPANISH_AND_ENGLISH.odt
```

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to TeX StackExchange! The error in your console isn't with picture_test.aux, and instead the file path of your English Orange English Bottle image. Could you please edit your question to share more details, like the directory structure of where your image file and .tex file are saved?

Comment: With LaTeX, aux files are not image files. They're used as a place for LaTeX to write information, which it can then read on its next run. Aux files are mostly used for situations where LaTeX needs to include information in a document, but it won't know the information until it finishes compiling (e.g. _what was the page number of that reference?_).

Comment: the error is not about the aux file which is unrelated to image inclusion but to a missing image file

Comment: @cfr ./ at the begin of a path is fine and even sometimes needed to restrict the search to the current directory.

Comment: is that log really from the code shown??? you have a duplicate FINAL PROOFS step in the path in the message `/BLUE_LAND_ORANGE_CARDS/` **FINAL_PROOFS/FINAL_PROOFS/** `1_ENGLISH_ORANGE_ENGLISH_BOTTLE.PNG`

Comment: Maybe just a typo somewhere? The error mentions `BLUE_LAND_ORANGE_CARDS` whereas the pwd mentions `BLUE_AND_ORANGE_CARDS` (without the `L` in front of `AND`. Also the path in the error contains the folder `FINAL_PROOFS` twice whereas in the file hierarchy it is shown only once, and the second one is written with a Q (FINAL_PRQOFS). So either there is a typo, or the log is not from the code as provides, or there is something _very_ strange going on with the filesystem.